# Where did Lothric Wyvern go?

Tags: dark-souls-3

At High Wall of Lothric in Dark Souls 3 you encounter a [dragon](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/enemygroup:lothric-wyvern) (Lothric Wyvern). At least that was a case for me at the begining of the game.

I collected all loot near it, but I never touched the dragon (I am sure of this, because I have no idea how to lure it out and fight it with a sword and I don't use bows and magic). Then, at the end of the playthrough I decided to visit the dragon and try to kill it. But there was no dragon... Where, when and why did it go?

P.S. I wonder if this is the one, which comes from the sky to Lothric Castle bridge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well first off,

If you wanted to kill it you couldn't. If you do enough damage to it (when you have it on High Wall of Lothric) it will simply fly away leaving a **Large Titanite Shard** behind.

To me the same thing happened. I went through the game and by curiosity I came back and the Wyvern was gone.

I revisited in 2 points of my game. One of them I saw the Wyvern again and the other no.

- **When I revisited and saw the Wyvern** I was messing around in the **Catacombs of Carthus**
- **When I revisited and didn't see any Wyvern** I had just been to Lothric Castle. Killed both Wyverns there.

One thing that I'm assuming is that it can be a bug that the developers overlooked. Or it might be that one of the Wyverns at Lothric Castle is the same at High Wall. Since I killed it, the Wyvern disappeared.

**EDIT**
Like **@fhlamarche** said in the comments below, he made a new character and instead of going to other areas, he went straight for the **Dancer of the Boreal Valley** and then to **Lothric Castle** (to the bridge).

There were the **2** Wyverns and when he came back to the **High Wall** there was no Wyvern to be seen.

Coupling the experiment with the fact that in the High Wall you can't kill the Wyvern (Like I said previously, it just flies away) it seems that the High Wall Wyvern **IS** one of the **Lothric Castle** Bridge Wyverns.

---

> **OLD**
>
> And I can't be certain because we can all speculate and later a patch
> comes and puts the Wyvern back in place.
>
> But all in all **I believe it to be one of the two Wyverns at Lothric
> Castle.**

Comment: Thanks, for additional info. Just to be sure: have you collected all items on the plato in front of the Wyvern and in the tower floor under it? I also wonder if it flies away once you learn to pass it, like the Hellkite Drake in DS1.

Comment: Yes I did collect every item. And no it doesn't fly away after you learn to pass it. For me it didn't

Comment: I believe it is the same Wyvern as the left one at Lothric Castle. I made a new character, killed the dancer early and went to the castle. Once I got to the bridge and triggered the wyverns, it was gone from the High Wall.

Comment: @fhlamarche, so you checked right before and after triggering the castle wyverns?

Comment: Well, not right before, but I didn't do anything else in between. I went through the room under the wyvern, lit the Tower bonfire, ran to Emma and killed her, then killed the Dancer, then ran to the bridge at Lothric Castle. I teleported back to the Tower bonfire and the wyvern was gone.

Comment: Yup. The wyvern is definetely one of the Lothric Castle ones. It doesn't even die. It just runs away so.

Comment: @klm123 I will update my answer to include his findings

Comment: @klm123 I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Lokuzt - You certainly can kill this dragon in Lothric, and it drops 37000 souls, etc.  The Claymore is on a raised ledge, and you can run up there, towards the dragon - clear of the flames, and hit the dragon with magic, etc,